# ActiveRecord search returns 'Syntax error or access violation' error

Tags: activerecord, yii, mysql-error-1064, yii-cmodel

In my Yii application, I have a model that represents `siteconfig` table and have four columns:

- integer `config_id`,
- string `key`,
- string `value`,
- string `update_time`.

I created a model using Gii (to ensure that I will not make any mistakes). I don't publish entire code here, cause this is 100% unmodified by me, standard model code generated by Gii. Since my problem is related to search, I only publish important part of generated code (the `search()` method):

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('config_id',$this->config_id);
    $criteria->compare('key',$this->key,true);
    $criteria->compare('value',$this->value,true);
    $criteria->compare('update_time',$this->update_time,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

I'm trying to use generated model in normal Yii ActiveRecord search like that:

```
$etona = new SiteConfigurationRecord();
$crit = new CDbCriteria();
$crit->select = "value";
$crit->condition = "key=:key";
$crit->params = array(":key"=>"sitename");
$etona = $etona->find($crit);
```

But, instead of getting expected search results, a strange (for me) error occurs:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'key='sitename' LIMIT 1' at line 1.
>   The SQL statement executed was: SELECT value FROM `siteconfig` `t`
>   WHERE key=:key LIMIT 1

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `key` for column name, which is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Yii uses [table alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail) in queries, but does not take any special care in case of reserverd word used as columns names. So, you have to take care of this by yourself.

For example:

```
$etona = new SiteConfigurationRecord();
$crit = new CDbCriteria();
$crit->select = "value";
$crit->condition = "t.key=:key"; // 't' is default alias
$crit->params = array(":key"=>"sitename");
$etona = $etona->find($crit);
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dmitry explained, SQL doesn't allow you to use the column name `key`. The Yii call in the code in your answer works because Yii performs parameter binding automatically, using names other than reserved words for the parameters. And it also uses fully-qualified column names (prefixes all column name references with `<tablename>.`, regardless of what invalid column name (reserved words) you pass the `findByAttributes` method.

Answer (score 0):

now it works.. ^^

i just use this code...

```
$etona = SiteConfigurationRecord::model()->findByAttributes(array('key'=>'sitename'));
```

maybe i need to study activerecord more somehow...

but still i don't know why the code above doesn't work