# Construct CDbCriteria with column names as MySQL reserved words

Tags: yii

I have exactly the same problem like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9835160/1469208) (attempt to use [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail) with column named `key`, which is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)). However, [provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836306/1469208):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->condition = 't.key=:key';
$criteria->params = array(':key'=>$this->key);
$criteria->compare('position', $this->position);
$criteria->compare('dictionary', $this->dictionary);
```

works for me only partially. I don't get exception anymore, but search works for `key` column only. All other are ignored (if `key` is set, respects only this value in search, if it is not set -- always returns empty results set).

What am I missing? How should I construct `CDbCriteria` queries, when my table contains reserverd words as column names, so search would respect all other (non-reserved) columns as well, not only this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CDbCriteria::compare()` adds condition only if parameter is set otherwise no action is taken.[See Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail)

```
$criteria->condition = 't.key=:key';
$criteria->params = array(':key'=>$this->key);
```

However this logic works irrespective of whether key is set or not. So basically your condition becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` t WHERE t.key =:key
```

even though the key value being blank resulting in your query breaking when key attribute is not set

So if you modify your statement like this then it work

```
if(isset($this->key){
    $criteria->condition = 't.key=:key';
    $criteria->params = array(':key'=>$this->key);
}
```

in this case this statement is only activated when key attribute is set, it is ignored otherwise, and your query will not break

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm accepting your answer, since there isn't any other. However, I must point out, that I haven't used (nor tested) your solution, because I found (at Yii forum) a [much easier solution to this problem](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55459-construct-cdbcriteria-with-column-names-as-mysql-reserved-words/page__view__findpost__p__253543) -- `$criteria->compare('t.key', $this->key);`. Works just fine.

Comment: thanks :) it works, i had similar problem with order keyword, that is also one way of doing it, using the table name explicitly also works